# Constrained Linear Regression with coefficients related by inequality

Tags: regression, modeling, least-squares, constrained-regression

I have a (slightly simplified) model of the following form:

$Y=c_1X_1 + c_2X_2 + \epsilon$ subject to the constraint $0\leq c_1\leq c_2$.

The distribution of $\epsilon$ is actually not important to me - fitting the curve by least squares is all I care about (for a volatility surface parameterization).

What is the best approach to solving this with deterministic results (i.e. not using iterative techniques dependent on starting points etc.).

I am working in C++ and I have Armadillo for my linear algebra library.

I am comfortable with python's libraries as well and R if necessary, but ultimate implementation will be C++.

Comment: Welcome to our site. As described in the answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29279, write your model as $$Y = c_1(X_1 + X_2) + (c_2-c_1)X_2 + \epsilon$$ subject to the constraint $(c_1,c_2-c_1)\ge(0,0)$ and search the solutions for "non-negative least squares" problems given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=non-negative+least+squares.

Comment: Thx - I knew it had to be something easy like this.  I'll be back in the swing of things soon - been a while since doing this kind of stuff.  I have to solve this problem a few thousand time a second, so we shall see how that goes.  len(Y) usually between 10-100. If speed is a problem, I can do usual OLS and it would be ok if sometimes the constraint fails as long enough of them do not - usually that is the case.

Comment: When the OLS solution doesn't work, you know at least one constraint holds.  It isn't too inefficient just to solve the resulting three possible models $Y=c_1(X_1+X_2)+\epsilon,$ $Y=c_2 X_2 + \epsilon,$ and $Y=\epsilon$ and select the one with least sum of squared residuals.  You could probably do up to a million of these a second (per core) by coding the procedure in a compiled language and perhaps a billion a second using a couple of high-end coprocessors, assuming you have the bandwidth to get all the data in quickly enough!

Comment: Good idea - when my data is good, the $R^2$ does need to be better than 0.99, so what I do is test a model such as $Y=c_1\rho X_1 + c_1 X_2$ where $|\rho|\leq 1$.  I test for 20 or 40 different $\rho$ from -1 to 1. (Note that this like solving the original problem where $0\leq |c_1| \leq c_2$ which is what I am really doing.

Comment: That looks like a hard way to do it.  Why not just use OLS to find $c_1$ and $c_2$ directly?

Comment: I do use OLS to get the $c_1$ with the fixed $\rho$ - the trouble is the OLS with $c_1$ and $c_2$  may imply a $\rho$ that is out of bounds.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136563/linear-regression-with-individual-constraints-in-r/136602#136602 for a working example.

Answer (score 1):

Reformulate your model to 
$$
   Y = c_1(X_1+X_2) + (c_2-c_1) X_2 + \epsilon
$$ (and probably an intercept which you have left out). Then the constraints is $0\le c_1, 0\le (c_2-c_1)$, and you can use an implementation of nonnegative least squares. In `R` there is a package `colf`, see an example in [Looking for function to fit sigmoid-like curve](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/206073/looking-for-function-to-fit-sigmoid-like-curve/316446#316446).  See also [Linear Regression with individual constraints in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136563/linear-regression-with-individual-constraints-in-r/136602#136602).

(This approach will be much simpler than what you propose in comments.)